# jmeter and azure devops load test, "At least one HTTP Request sampler should be present and enabled"

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, load-testing

I have a simple test script which I recorded using out of the box JMeter and the recording template. I recorded a simple page, which create a "recording controller" in the threadgroup, and below that the pages "http requests".

When I upload this to the Azure DevOps JMeter runner, I get the error:

`At least one HTTP Request sampler should be present and enabled.`

Is there any way to get round this?

I am not sure why the `http request` is not recognised as a sampler. I am using JMeter 5.3. I know azure only supports 3.x, but till now this has not been an issue.

Comment: Could you show the screenshot of your testplan or upload it to somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried to record the same script in JMeter 3.x and upload this one?

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.x to 5.3 there are could be many incompatible changes.

There are two bugs fixed in HTTP Samplers block in JMeter 5.3, [Release Notes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) says.
And one of them marked as an **Incompatible changes**:

> Default value of `httpclient4.time_to_live` has been modified from `2000`
> to `60000`, this means HTTP connections will live longer than before.
> This has impact on connection creation and SSL handshake, see [Bug 64289](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64289)

So, try to record your script in previous version of JMeter, the best choice is JMeter 3.x, if Azure supports only 3.x.